# Unable to inject data into template with html-webpack-plugin

Tags: webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I've tried to get custom data injected into our .html template using this loader without any success. We've been able to successfully build our assets and have them injected, however, the ability to pass in dynamic data has not worked. Looking at the examples provided in this repo, I don't see how options.title is passed into the template.

I'm using this starter kit, which is quite simple with this plugin: https://github.com/AngularClass/NG6-starter

Here are the versions of the relevant dependencies:

```
"webpack": "^2.2.1"
"html-webpack-plugin": "^2.29.0"
```

Copy the relevant section from webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: {
    app: [
      'babel-polyfill',
      path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'app/app.js')
    ]
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
       { test: /\.js$/, exclude: [/app\/lib/, /node_modules/], loader: 'ng-annotate-loader!babel-loader' },
       { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'raw-loader' }, // have also tried with the html-loader
       { test: /\.(scss|sass)$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader' },
       { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader' }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    // Injects bundles in your index.html instead of wiring all manually.
    // It also adds hash to all injected assets so we don't have problems
    // with cache purging during deployment.
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'client/index.html',
      // inject: 'body',
      // hash: true,
      title: 'TEST!!!!!!!!!!!',
      options: {
        title: "TEST!!!!!!!!!!!!!*"
      },
      chunks: ['vendor', 'app']
    }),

    // Automatically move all modules defined outside of application directory to vendor bundle.
    // If you are using more complicated project structure, consider to specify common chunks manually.
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: "vendor",
      minChunks: module => /node_modules/.test(module.resource)
    })
  ]
};
```

Template file

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
    <meta name="description" content="NG6-Starter by @AngularClass">
    <link rel="icon" href="data:;base64,iVBORw0KGgo=">
    <base href="/">
  </head>
  <body ng-app="app" ng-strict-di ng-cloak>


  <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %>

  <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.title %>

  <%= title %>

  <%= '\<\%\= htmlWebpackPlugin.title \%\>' %>

  <%= '\<\%\= htmlWebpackPlugin.options \%\>' %>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the issue is that the `html` or `raw` loader is taking control of all of the `.html` files, so the `html-webpack-plugin` wasn't able to do what it needed. What you essentially need to do is have the `raw` or `html` loader point at everything, as needed, but to exclude the `template` file passed to `html-webpack-plugin`.

Reference: https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/issues/747#issuecomment-316804313

Comment: This answer is hacky as it just excludes a non html file from your html loaders list

Answer (score 11):

The correct option is:

```
<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %>
```

This is [EJS](https://github.com/mde/ejs) syntax. It evaluates the expression and puts the result into the HTML in its place. That means it needs to be in the `<head>` like so:

```
<title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
```

The reason that your template is not working, is because you've configured `raw-loader` to be used for `.html` files. That means the template is treated as an HTML file. `html-webpack-plugin` a fallback ejs loader, which is only used if there's no loader configured for a given file. It's a good idea to use `.ejs` instead of `.html` for the template, to not conflict the loaders. See also [The template option](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/blob/master/docs/template-option.md) for other solutions (e.g. if you want to use another template engine).

Rename `client/index.html` to `client/index.ejs`.

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: 'client/index.ejs',
  // inject: 'body',
  // hash: true,
  title: 'TEST!!!!!!!!!!!',
  chunks: ['vendor', 'app']
}),
```

The repository you linked uses old versions of many things (`webpack` and `html-webpack-plugin` for instance) and it appears that the version of `html-webpack-plugin` does not work with the above configuration. You need to upgrade it with:

```
npm install --save-dev html-webpack-plugin@latest
```

Comment: I have also tried this and added the `ejs-loader`. It was still the same ordeal. If you can get that to work with the starter kit I provided above, you'd be a badass

Comment: It turns out that the `html-webpack-plugin` was outdated and didn't work. Upgrading it, makes it work just fine.

Comment: That wasn't the issue, unfortunately. It was simply an issue with how `html-webpack-plugin` handles files in combination with the loaders. I posted the link to the required fix...

Comment: It's basically the same solution, but using a more restrictive regex instead of changing the file to an `.ejs` to avoid using the loader for the template.

Comment: I tried the `.ejs` as well, but what happens, is that the `.ejs` converts the file to `.html`, which brings us back to the same issue. Feel free to give it a try with the boilerplate code I provided above...

Comment: I did. That's how I figured out that `html-webpack-plugin` needs to be upgraded for it to work.

Answer (score 7):

You can do the following without extra loaders (at least with `html-webpack-plugin@3.2.0`):

```js
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: 'index.html',
  templateParameters: {
    title: 'foo',
    content: 'bar'
  }
})
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title><%= title %></title>
</head>

<body>
  <p><%= content %></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Note that this is EJS syntax, but it works in regular `.html` files, too.

Comment: It's not working for me with `html-webpack-plugin@5.1.0`